# Is there a way to programatically identify the status of a tcp connection/port?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, networking, tcp

I get a port after seeing the $DISPLAY environment variable, and need to check if the vnc on which the current program is run is connected or not.

```
❯ netstat -an --tcp | grep 5902
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5902            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
```

The above is a netstat output.

On tcp connection established for the port, the following is the output:

```
$ netstat -an --tcp | grep 5902
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5902            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 172.16.100.219:5902     172.16.100.129:35542    ESTABLISHED
```

One can call netstat from within C/c++ code something like

```
port = process_display(std::getenv("DISPLAY"))
is_connected = call_this("netstat -anp | grep <porttocheck> | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l");
```

I need the `is_connected` and do some logic.

However, this relies on variety of factors, if the program is going to run on different machines, I would rather not rely on calling netstat from code.

Is there a better way to check if a port has a established TCP connection, from C code? Parsing /proc/ or something similar also looks very unweildy.

I am ok for a linux only solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I know no clean and simple way to list all the current network connections on one machine. It is indeed possible because netstat does it but I am afraid that on Linux it does so by using very low level data. IMHO, the best you can do is to look at netstat source and see whether you prefere to mimic it or directly call the netstat program

Comment: [This](http://procps.sourceforge.net/) might help you.

Comment: For Linux only, I did that in the past reading /proc/net/tcp and/or /proc/net/tcp6. You have socket local and remote address and status there, that should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create a socket with the port which you want the status of it. If socket successfully created it means that the port was closed otherwise it is open. [like this](http://systhread.net/texts/200909netconn4.php)